# rails method like `cast_to_current_sti_type`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

is there a rails method that works like this:

```
@some_record.becomes(@some_record[@some_record.class.sti_column])
```

if i was creating such a method it would look approx like this:

```
def cast_to_current_sti_type
  self.becomes(self[self.class.sti_column])
end
```

I'm just figuring it might already exist in ActiveRecord someplace.

I guess there is some confusion about WHY you want this method...

Lets say some place in the code this happens

foo.type = "User"

and elsewhere in the code you have `bar` which is already loaded and pointing to the same record as `foo`, and infact is the same AR instance as foo.

I want to be able to say:

bar.cast_to_current_sti_type

Which will return a new instance but of the right type

Like I point out above... I can always create a method which does exactly what I need (using becomes and the sti_column)  I just figured it probably already exists in rails...

Comment: There is a becomes method , what are you trying to acomplish ? Could you give more info ?

Comment: @GorillaApe yes there is a becomes method... notice I used in the above.  I want a method that given an AR instance returns an instance that would be returned as if you did a `becomes` using the current sti type.  I can accomplish what I wish using the method I defined.  I am wondering if that method (or similar) already exists.

Comment: Since there is support out of the box for Single Table Inheritance by using column named type or self.inheritance_column = :whatever active record automatically casts to the type you need. Isnt that what you want ?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-inheritance_column